Prisma - adding a new property to mongoDB
Is there a way to add a new property (with default value) to mongoDB while pushing changes?
I've got a simple model
model Task {
  id                  String        @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  name                String        @unique
  createdAt           DateTime      @default(now())
  updatedAt           DateTime      @updatedAt
}

and I want to add a property
  completed           Boolean       @default(false)

Can it be done automatically? Or the only way is to write a simple JS script to overwrite my existing Tasks?
I tried with db push, migrate dev and generating new connection - no changes in mongoDB. I want to automatically seed my current tasks with my new property and default value.
